# How to control naming of the nested parts of the KML using ArcPy LayerToKML

Tags: arcpy, kmz

Using the ArcPy [Layer To KML (Conversion) tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/layer-to-kml.htm), how can I control the naming of the nesting in the KMZ structure?

My code gives me this:

[image]

I don't know why it chose the field that has the name "Oregon" (that field name is "state_name" in the SHP). I would like for it to use the "county_name" field.

How can I control the output so that it is like this:

[image]

```
## steps
# specify county (done in loop, simplified here)
# define selection criteria
# convert SHP to Layer for use in Select function
# select subset
# save to KMZ

c = 'Lincoln'
criteria = '"county_name" = {}'.format(c)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(myfile.shp, 'myLayer')
subset = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('myLayer', "NEW_SELECTION", criteria)
arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(subset, 'myoutput.kmz')
```